Is there a way to make the bars' colors conditional to the column?
I would like to make the colors of the bars in the column "Percentile" conditional to the value, meaning that if the value is between 100-90 it has one color, if it's between 90-80 it's another color, and so on...
This is the table in question:
player_percentiles %>%
    gt() %>%
    gt_plt_bar_pct(Percentile, labels = F, fill = "black") %>%
    cols_width(Percentile ~ px(200)) %>%
    opt_row_striping() %>%
    cols_align(align = "left", columns = Stat) %>%
    cols_align(align = "center", columns = Percentile) %>%
    opt_stylize(style = 1, color = "gray") %>%
    cols_label(perc_value = "") %>%
    tab_style(
        style = cell_text(color = "darkred"),
        locations = cells_body(columns = perc_value)
    )

And just in case, a glimpse of the tibble used for the table:
# A tibble: 23 × 4
   Stat                         `Per 90` perc_value Percentile
   <fct>                        <chr>         <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 Passes Completed             64.3             94         94
 2 Passes Attempted             75.9             94         94
 3 Pass Completion %            84.1%            65         65
 4 Total Passing Distance       1177.9           96         96
 5 Progressive Passing Distance 345.5            95         95
 6 Progressive Distance %       29.4%            61         61
 7 Short Passes Completed       27.5             86         86
 8 Short Passes Attempted       30.2             86         86
 9 Short Pass Completion %      90.8%            73         73
10 Medium Passes Completed      26.9             94         94
# ℹ 13 more rows

And the dput() of the tibble
dput(player_percentiles)

structure(list(Stat = structure(1:23, levels = c("Passes Completed", 
"Passes Attempted", "Pass Completion %", "Total Passing Distance", 
"Progressive Passing Distance", "Progressive Distance %", "Short Passes Completed", 
"Short Passes Attempted", "Short Pass Completion %", "Medium Passes Completed", 
"Medium Passes Attempted", "Medium Pass Completion %", "Long Passes Completed", 
"Long Passes Attempted", "Long Pass Completion %", "Assists", 
"xAG: Exp. Assisted Goals", "xA: Expected Assists", "Key Passes", 
"Passes into Final 1/3", "Passes into Penalty Area", "Crosses into Penalty Area", 
"Progressive Passes"), class = "factor"), `Per 90` = c("64.3", 
"75.9", "84.1%", "1177.9", "345.5", "29.4%", "27.5", "30.2", 
"90.8%", "26.9", "30.2", "88.6%", "8.1", "11.3", "70.8%", "0.08", 
"0.13", "0.14", "1.32", "7.31", "1.78", "0.17", "8.64"), perc_value = c(94, 
94, 65, 96, 95, 61, 86, 86, 73, 94, 96, 68, 98, 95, 80, 46, 69, 
73, 66, 95, 92, 63, 96), Percentile = c(94, 94, 65, 96, 95, 61, 
86, 86, 73, 94, 96, 68, 98, 95, 80, 46, 69, 73, 66, 95, 92, 63, 
96)), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

Any help is highly appreciated!

A preferred solution would be to register a table draw callback, but I could not figure out how to do that with {gt}.
Instead, a similar approach would be to borrow from the answer to this question and start an interval when the table is generated in a reactive value. This interval is executed every 10ms until it finds the table tds whereupon it cancels itself and proceeds to set the bar colors.
Shiny Example Code
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

player_percentiles <- structure(
  list(
    Stat = structure(
      1:23,
      levels = c(
        "Passes Completed",
        "Passes Attempted",
        "Pass Completion %",
        "Total Passing Distance",
        "Progressive Passing Distance",
        "Progressive Distance %",
        "Short Passes Completed",
        "Short Passes Attempted",
        "Short Pass Completion %",
        "Medium Passes Completed",
        "Medium Passes Attempted",
        "Medium Pass Completion %",
        "Long Passes Completed",
        "Long Passes Attempted",
        "Long Pass Completion %",
        "Assists",
        "xAG: Exp. Assisted Goals",
        "xA: Expected Assists",
        "Key Passes",
        "Passes into Final 1/3",
        "Passes into Penalty Area",
        "Crosses into Penalty Area",
        "Progressive Passes"
      ),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    `Per 90` = c(
      "64.3",
      "75.9",
      "84.1%",
      "1177.9",
      "345.5",
      "29.4%",
      "27.5",
      "30.2",
      "90.8%",
      "26.9",
      "30.2",
      "88.6%",
      "8.1",
      "11.3",
      "70.8%",
      "0.08",
      "0.13",
      "0.14",
      "1.32",
      "7.31",
      "1.78",
      "0.17",
      "8.64"
    ),
    perc_value = c(
      94,
      94,
      65,
      96,
      95,
      61,
      86,
      86,
      73,
      94,
      96,
      68,
      98,
      95,
      80,
      46,
      69,
      73,
      66,
      95,
      92,
      63,
      96
    ),
    Percentile = c(
      94,
      94,
      65,
      96,
      95,
      61,
      86,
      86,
      73,
      94,
      96,
      68,
      98,
      95,
      80,
      46,
      69,
      73,
      66,
      95,
      92,
      63,
      96
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -23L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(), gt_output("gtout"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  gtrv <- reactiveVal({
    player_percentiles %>%
      gt() %>%
      gt_plt_bar_pct(Percentile, labels = F, fill = "black") %>%
      cols_width(Percentile ~ px(200)) %>%
      opt_row_striping() %>%
      cols_align(align = "left", columns = Stat) %>%
      cols_align(align = "center", columns = Percentile) %>%
      opt_stylize(style = 1, color = "gray") %>%
      cols_label(perc_value = "") %>%
      tab_style(style = cell_text(color = "darkred"),
                locations = cells_body(columns = perc_value))
  })
  
  output$gtout <- render_gt({ gtrv() })
  
  observeEvent(gtrv, { 
    runjs('
var watch_for_gt_draw = setInterval(function() {
  var tds = $( "td[headers=\'Percentile\'] > div > div" );
  if(tds) {
    clearInterval(watch_for_gt_draw);
    
    tds.each(function() {
      var p = $( this ).width() / $( this ).parent().width();
      
      var b = "#FFFFFF";
      
      if (p <= 0.1) {
        b = "#000000";
      } else if (p <= 0.2) {
        b = "#1C0000";
      } else if (p <= 0.3) {
        b = "#380000";
      } else if (p <= 0.4) {
        b = "#550000";
      } else if (p <= 0.5) {
        b = "#710000";
      } else if (p <= 0.6) {
        b = "#8D0000";
      } else if (p <= 0.7) {
        b = "#AA0000";
      } else if (p <= 0.8) {
        b = "#C60000";
      } else if (p <= 0.9) {
        b = "#E20000";
      } else if (p <= 1.0) {
        b = "#FF0000";
      }
      
      $( this ).css("background", b);
    });
  } 
}, 10);
'
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Output


It's a great solution but he problem is that I don't plan on knitting to html

what is your target format?

Well I plan to use the table in a shiny app, the problem is that I don't really know how to apply your js code in that context

@LucasVarela updated for shiny

Hey mate, this was really helpful. Unfortunately now it stopped applying th js code to the gt table after I changed the names from gtout to gtout_passing and grtv to grtv_passing. The problem seems to be with the js code which I can't check since I do not know about js. Is there a part in the js code that depends to a certain object name?

The JS codes itself does not know about the R object names so not really. Shiny will run the JS whenever it detects a change to the reactive value. If a change is detected, the JS code looks for html elements with the "td[headers='Percentile'] > div > div" CSS selector which represent the bars. Make sure you changed gtout in two places and gtrv in three places, and make sure you did not change the table itself because otherwise you may need a different CSS selector in the JS.

Here is a better example that makes use of a color gradient and listens to the shiny value output event.
Contents of javascript-color-gradient.js
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-color-gradient

class GradientColor {
  constructor(startColor = "", endColor = "", minNum = 0, maxNum = 10) {
    this.setColorGradient = (colorStart, colorEnd) => {
      startColor = getHexColor(colorStart);
      endColor = getHexColor(colorEnd);
    };

    this.setMidpoint = (minNumber, maxNumber) => {
      minNum = minNumber;
      maxNum = maxNumber;
    };

    this.getColor = (numberValue) => {
      if (numberValue) {
        return (
          "#" +
          generateHex(
            numberValue,
            startColor.substring(0, 2),
            endColor.substring(0, 2)
          ) +
          generateHex(
            numberValue,
            startColor.substring(2, 4),
            endColor.substring(2, 4)
          ) +
          generateHex(
            numberValue,
            startColor.substring(4, 6),
            endColor.substring(4, 6)
          )
        );
      }
    };

    const generateHex = (number, start, end) => {
      if (number < minNum) {
        number = minNum;
      } else if (number > maxNum) {
        number = maxNum;
      }

      const midPoint = maxNum - minNum;
      const startBase = parseInt(start, 16);
      const endBase = parseInt(end, 16);
      const average = (endBase - startBase) / midPoint;
      const finalBase = Math.round(average * (number - minNum) + startBase);
      const balancedFinalBase =
        finalBase < 16 ? "0" + finalBase.toString(16) : finalBase.toString(16);
      return balancedFinalBase;
    };

    const getHexColor = (color) => {
      return color.substring(color.length - 6, color.length);
    };
  }
}

class Gradient {
  constructor(
    colorGradients = "",
    maxNum = 10,
    colors = ["", ""],
    intervals = []
  ) {
    const setColorGradient = (gradientColors) => {
      if (gradientColors.length < 2) {
        throw new Error(
          `setColorGradient should have more than ${gradientColors.length} color`
        );
      } else {
        const increment = maxNum / (gradientColors.length - 1);
        const firstColorGradient = new GradientColor();
        const lower = 0;
        const upper = 0 + increment;
        firstColorGradient.setColorGradient(
          gradientColors[0],
          gradientColors[1]
        );
        firstColorGradient.setMidpoint(lower, upper);
        colorGradients = [firstColorGradient];
        intervals = [
          {
            lower,
            upper,
          },
        ];

        for (let i = 1; i < gradientColors.length - 1; i++) {
          const gradientColor = new GradientColor();
          const lower = 0 + increment * i;
          const upper = 0 + increment * (i + 1);
          gradientColor.setColorGradient(
            gradientColors[i],
            gradientColors[i + 1]
          );
          gradientColor.setMidpoint(lower, upper);
          colorGradients[i] = gradientColor;
          intervals[i] = {
            lower,
            upper,
          };
        }
        colors = gradientColors;
      }
    };

    this.setColorGradient = (...gradientColors) => {
      setColorGradient(gradientColors);
      return this;
    };

    this.getColors = () => {
      const gradientColorsArray = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < intervals.length; j++) {
        const interval = intervals[j];
        const start = interval.lower === 0 ? 1 : Math.ceil(interval.lower);
        const end =
          interval.upper === maxNum
            ? interval.upper + 1
            : Math.ceil(interval.upper);
        for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
          gradientColorsArray.push(colorGradients[j].getColor(i));
        }
      }
      return gradientColorsArray;
    };

    this.getColor = (numberValue) => {
      if (isNaN(numberValue)) {
        throw new TypeError(`getColor should be a number`);
      } else if (numberValue <= 0) {
        throw new TypeError(`getColor should be greater than ${numberValue}`);
      } else {
        const toInsert = numberValue + 1;
        const segment = (maxNum - 0) / colorGradients.length;
        const index = Math.min(
          Math.floor((Math.max(numberValue, 0) - 0) / segment),
          colorGradients.length - 1
        );
        return colorGradients[index].getColor(toInsert);
      }
    };

    this.setMidpoint = (maxNumber) => {
      if (!isNaN(maxNumber) && maxNumber >= 0) {
        maxNum = maxNumber;
        setColorGradient(colors);
      } else if (maxNumber <= 0) {
        throw new RangeError(`midPoint should be greater than ${maxNumber}`);
      } else {
        throw new RangeError("midPoint should be a number");
      }
      return this;
    };
  }
}

Contents of shiny_value_listener.js
// listen to shiny output events
$(document).on('shiny:value', function(event) {  
  // for gt_out events
  if (event.target.id === 'gt_out') {
    const id = 'gt_out';
    
    // generate a 100 point color gradient
    const gradientArray = new Gradient()
      .setColorGradient("#000000", "00FF00")
      .setMidpoint(100);
    
    // temporarily place the freshly rendered table into the #gtout 
    // div to be replaced later with the modified version
    $( '#' + id ).html(event.value.html);
    
    // for each bar element
    $( "#" + id + " > div > table > tbody > tr > td[headers='x'] > div > div" )
      .each(function() {
        // calculate rendered width as a percent
        var p = $( this ).width() / $( this ).parent().width();
          
        // retrive the corresponding color
        var i = Math.round(100 * p);
        var b = gradientArray.getColor(i);
        
        // set bar color
        $( this ).css('background', b);
      });
    
    // copy modified table back to event data to allow 
    // default processing to use our modified table
    event.value.html = $( '#' + id ).html();
  }
});

Contents of app.R
library(gtExtras)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  includeScript("javascript-color-gradient.js"),
  includeScript("shiny_value_listener.js"),
  gt_output("gt_out")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$gt_out <- render_gt({
    data.frame(x = seq(10, 100, 10)) |> 
      gt() |>
      gt_plt_bar_pct(column = x, labels = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Output

Reprex files hosted with  on GitHub

A simple approach entirely in base R:
# make a colour scheme from black to red with 10 steps
black_to_red=colorRampPalette( c("black","red") )(10)

# set the plot area to make room for the long labels
par( plt=c(0.5,0.9,0.1,0.9) )

# plot a bar graph, specifying the colours for each bar
barplot( data$Percentile, col=black_to_red[ data$Percentile/10 ],
    names.arg=data$Stat, las=2, horiz=T)


